# Does restriction on starting activity from foreground service in new android versions apply to starting of activity by clicking noti?

Tags: android

I am not sure to what extent the foreground service restriction goes. Basically, I want my app to keep **either an activity running by itself, or foreground service running notification**.

The user would transition to either mode as necessary manually (ie; keep/kill the current mode as the user transition).

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/foreground-services

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've read it. I am not really sure if it really answers my question. It says an app in the background cannot start a foreground service. But I want to know if a foreground service can start an activity *with user intervention* like user expanding the notification widget and clicking on a button to start an activity.

Comment: I'm using a "transparent (and without UI) launcherActivity" to launch my App which starts my main ForegroundService. So I think it's possibile to launch a "fake" Activity which starts a ForegroundService even if the main one is still in Background.... (I never tried this but I think it will work)

Comment: Hmm also see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions